Let a view show the details for selected entries of two other views in rcp e4
My application contains three views: On the left side view "A" and view "B" each with a list of table entries and on the right side the view "Details" that shows the details for the selected entries of view "A" or view "B" depending on which view was activated as last on the left side.
It works with rcp3 but I can't find an equivalent solution for rcp e4.
In rcp3 it is implemented with the workbench site selection provider like this:
ViewA:
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI);
    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setInput(Arrays.asList("A1", "A2", "A3"));

    getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
}

ViewB:
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI);
    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setInput(Arrays.asList("B1", "B2", "B3"));
        
    getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
}

DetailsView:
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    detailsLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    detailsLabel.setText("");
        
    getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(ViewA.ID, this);
    getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(ViewB.ID, this);
}
public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
    if (part instanceof ViewA || part instanceof ViewB){
        showDetailsOfEntries(
            selection instanceof IStructuredSelection structuredSelection ?
            structuredSelection.toList() : Collections.emptyList() );
    }
}
private void showDetailsOfEntries( List<?> entries) {
    String details = entries.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    detailsLabel.setText(details);
    composite.layout(true);
}

I can switch back and forth between "A" and "B", and the "Details" view show the details of the selected entries of "A" or "B".
I tried to migrate this to rcp e4:
ViewA und ViewB:
@Inject
private ESelectionService selectionService

@PostConstruct
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ...
    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(event -> {
        selectionService.setSelection(event.getSelection());
});

DetailsView:
@Inject
private ESelectionService selectionService

@PostConstruct
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ...
    selectionService.addSelectionListener(ViewA.ID, this);
    selectionService.addSelectionListener(ViewB.ID, this);
}
public void selectionChanged(MPart part, Object selection) {
    if (part.getElementId().equals(ViewA.ID) || part.getElementId().equals(ViewB.ID)) {
        ...
    }
}

But now the behavior is different. Switching between the views "A" and "B" don't change the selection and so there is no update in the "Details" view. The "selectionChanged" method in "Details" view is now only be called if there is a new selection in view "A" or "B" and not when switching between view "A" and "B" as it was in rcp3.
How can I achieve the old behavior?

You probably have to use EPartService.addPartListener to listen for the active part changing. At a quick look that is roughly what the e3 WorkbenchPage selection service is doing.

I added a part listener to details view with public void partActivated( MPart part ){ if (part.getElementId().equals(ViewA.ID) || part.getElementId().equals(ViewB.ID)) { selectionChanged(part, selectionService.getSelection(part.getElementId())); }} and it works. Thank you very much!

In this solution the active selection in view A or B may be incorrect and can contain the selection of the other view, because both views use the selection service to set the active selection if the viewer's selection has changed, but not on view activation. So a handler with @Optional @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) IStructuredSelection selection for view A, acts on the selection of view B, if I first navigate to view B, select an item and switch back to view A and open the context menu by clicking on the empty space in the table in view A.

Removing the part listener from details view and adding part listeners to view A and B with partActivated implemented as if (part.getElementId().equals(ID)) { viewer.setSelection(viewer.getSelection(), true); } seems to be a better solution. This updates the active selection for this view and informs the details view about the changed selection.
